# xcode 4.6 dp cfnetwork.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode

I moved to xcode 4.6 dp4. My app run fine on simulator (any version from 5.0 to 6.1) but fails to compile on device (running iOS 5.1).

The error is:

[image]

Help appreciated.

Max

Comment: Isn't Xcode 4.6 still under NDA?  If so discuss this on https://devforums.apple.com

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall fixed the problem. Thanks.